# 406 error when template and partial exist as well as when they don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a 406 error and it's rendering a blank white page, even though the log makes it look like it's rendering my shared/404 page. I can even remove the layout and 404 page and same error. Any ideas?

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-19 22:26:56 -0800
  Processing by MinisitesController#show as HTML
  Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."full_domain" = 'test.eg.local' AND (accounts.deleted_at IS NULL) LIMIT 1
Rendered shared/404.html.haml (0.3ms)
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 81ms (Views: 12.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
```